# Sending signed emails using PHP

Tags: php, email, openssl, phpmailer, sign

What I would like to achieve is being able to send signed emails so that users' email clients show such mails as trusted (e.g. in Thunderbird sometimes such emails are marked with a closed envelope icon).

I found a PHPMailer library which is supposed to send signed emails, but I think it just wraps the openssl_pkcs7_sign PHP function. I am not sure what are and how to get and use keys and certificates which are function's arguments. There are to parameters: $signcert and $privkey. From what I understand the $signcert should be publicly known certificate used to verify that the message was properly signed. The $privkey is something coupled with the certificate, should be kept in secret and is used to sign emails. Am I correct so far?

My problem is how to get proper certificates. I think OpenSSL allows me to generate my own certs, but are such certs sufficient enough for my needs? If they are, how do I generate them properly? I mean there might be certificates of different length and other options which might be important and I am unaware of. And by the way, I noticed that "https" self signed certs cause warnings in browsers. Does same thing happen with mails? In that case probably I should buy certificate from trusted cert center. Can you give me an advice which centers I should consider?

Comment: Just an FYI - secure email is not universally supported, unlike HTTPS. This is because for the most part quite a bit of the mail systems don't automatically support it (Outlook, for instance, still doesn't ship with it enabled). As an alternative, you might look into something like [Hushmail](http://www.hushmail.com/), which provides intermediary systems for accomplishing this consistently. However, consider that if you send any mail to a server that can then be decrypted by that server only (and not the user's personal cert), it is inherently insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here [1] it is implied that the certificate used to sign emails must be issued by Certification Authority (so the email client won't give any warnings). The list of some Authorities which issue free certificates can be found here: [2]. The one I have chosen gives the certificate by installing it directly to a web browser. So to do something more, it should be exported. Popular format is *.p12, which can store both public and private key. But it seems that using PHP function `openssl_pkcs7_sign()` and pointing it's arguments to the file with both certificates doesn't work - OpenSSL returns ambigous error `error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line`. After separating keys (using OpenSSL) signing works fine.

By the way, even though the PHPMailer is supposed to be capable of singing emails, it's current version doesn't work. Mail is being signed, stored in a temporary file, the file is deleted and after that the content of the file is send (so the message is empty).

[1] - http://kb.mozillazine.org/Message_security

[2] - http://kb.mozillazine.org/Getting_an_SMIME_certificate

Answer (score 2):

> I think OpenSSL allows me to generate my own certs, but are such certs sufficient enough for my needs?

We don't know what your needs are.

A certificate on its own is useless for signing of messages. The value comes where that certificate is itself (verifiably) authenticated by a third party acceptable to both the the sender and resipient. This 3rd party is the Certification Authority (e.g. Thawte, Verisign etc) although within an organisation it may be sufficient to provide your own CA. The OpenSSL documents explain in detail how to create your own CA certificaet which you can use to sign other certificates.

You've got a long learning journey ahead of you before you'll be able to implement any code - you could do worse than start with the openssl howto and x509 cerificates howto.

Comment: Just wondering, do you know of any good books that really help explain the different crypt techniques (preferably with visualizations)? I've been working to improve my understanding and I'm just not finding what I'm looking for.